# Detect autofilter on Excel Tables

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

Below line detects if there are active `AutoFilter` in a sheet.

```
Debug.Print Sheet1.AutoFilterMode
```

This returns `True` if there are active filters in Sheet1, `False` otherwise.
My problem is, this doesn't detect `AutoFilter` on *Tables*. 
Is there a way to detect `AutoFilterMode` on *Tables*, a property I might have missed?

Comment: `? activesheet.listobjects(1).showautofilter`

Comment: @TimWilliams Haha I was looking on the wrong  list. :) To lazy to scroll down till `S`. Please post it as answer so I can accept it and for others reference as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
activesheet.listobjects(1).showautofilter
```

will be True if the Autofilter controls are showing.